# If a queryset value is in a list

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python but am surprised I can't find another post with a similar question to mine. I'm trying to find a way to compare whether a queryset value is inside a list. Take this as an example:

```
account_roles = <QuerySet [<Group: admin>, <Group: customer>]>
allowed_roles = ['admin', 'customer', 'supplier', 'observer']

if account_roles in allowed_roles:
   print('Authorised')
```

Essentially a user has `account_roles` and I only want to print 'authorised' if a user with an `admin` or `customer` role is present. I can only get a comparison working for a single value, but an the entire list of values.

Example working for a single value only:

```
if request.user.groups.exists():
   group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

if group in allowed_roles:
   return view_fn(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Can someone show me how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find out if there exists a `Group` with a `.name` of the group that is in the list. We can filter with an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) and query with:

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=allowed_roles).exists():
    # has such group …
else:
    # user is not a member of any allowed_roles …
```

Comment: thank you, that's useful. What is the double underscore __ convention? Is there a page with information about it because I've seen it elsewhere and thought that was only a convention and that you could not filter that way

Comment: @user8758206: that is an `in` lookup: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

Answer (score 2):

if queryset.filter(name__in=allowed_roles).exists():

For more info refer documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/